# Enumerating special Matrices

Tags: algorithms, matrices

Is there an efficient algorithm for enumerating binary $n\times n$ matrices which are such that each row has  1's and each column also has  1's?

Related - https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3484685/counting-matrices

Comment: It might help in finding references that this is equivalent to enumerating k-regular bipartite graphs with 2n vertices.

Comment: http://users.cecs.anu.edu.au/~bdm/data/graphs.html